# Latest version of IoT Edge installing old services/modules

Tags: azure-iot-edge

Installed version 1.4.9.10083 of Azure IoT Edge LTS on Windows 10.  Microsoft update catalog shows that i have the latest version.

`iotedge check` indicates that there are newer services/packages/modules available:  [iot edge check results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBUK.png)

How do I update aziot-identity-service and aziot-edge to the latest versions.

thanks

I installed the latest version of IoT Edge from the Update catalog and expected to have the latest versions installed, i.e. a clean iotedge check report.

Comment: Hope this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/iot-edge-for-linux-on-windows?view=iotedge-1.4) [helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-update-iot-edge?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=windows)

Comment: 1.4.20 has not yet been released for Eflow. When it is, Windows update will pick it up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! The documentation link [Offline or specific version installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal%2Cubuntu#offline-or-specific-version-installation-optional) provides steps needed to download and install a specific version of the `aziot-identity-service` and `aziot-edge`.

You can find the available latest releases and versions from the link [Azure IoT Edge releases](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases). You can find the latest versions of IoT Edge daemon and Identity service packages under the Assets section of IoT Edge 1.4.20 LTS version. You can follow the steps provided in the article [Offline or specific version installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-provision-single-device-linux-symmetric?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=azure-portal%2Cubuntu#offline-or-specific-version-installation-optional) to update to the packages to their latest versions.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful although I'm using EFlow on Windows 10, so I'm not sure if the linux instructions apply.  According the EFlow doc (as I understand it...) EFlow is supposed to update with Windows Update.